# Html.AntiForgeryToken Helper not rendering request validation token hidden field in form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Following code in razor view is not creating HTML with input type hidden with name "__RequestVerificationToken" strange. I have "LogOff" action decorated with attribute "ValidateAntiForgeryToken".

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <input type="submit" value="LogOff" />
}
```

What does I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

not

```
Html.AntiForgeryToken();
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen, stupid mistake from my side. I thoughtusing '@' begins block of code and anything inside this block would not need to have '@' again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
@Html.AntiforgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary() //if needed

and also check if there is the 
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attributes placed on your action method.
Hope this helps.
Thanks